# Windows Identity framework with windows XP

Tags: .net, security, identity, federated-identity, claims-based-identity

How can use the [Windows Identity Foundation SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c148b2df-c7af-46bb-9162-2c9422208504&displaylang=en) with Windows XP ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Windows Identity Framework is not supported on Windows XP.

Comment: Does this mean a client developed using WIF cannot be deployed to Windows XP machines?

Comment: @NeilBarnwell I'd be "very surprised" if it worked; irrespective, it would not be a supported configuration by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, WIF requires:

- Microsoft Windows **Vista SP1**, **Windows 7**, or Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (32-bit/64-bit)
- Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0
- Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
- Windows Identity Foundation
- Microsoft Visual Studio® 2008 SP1

Two samples require additionally:
* Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
* ASP.NET MVC 1.0